# Issue while installing flex layout

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

I am trying to install `flex-layout` using this command `npm install --save @angular/flex-layout`.

I am getting these errors:

[image]

**node version: v10.1.0

npm version: 6.0.1

Angular : 6.1.2**

I have created many `branches` for the project in `Visual studio code(vscode)`,In the last `branch` this installation was successful and in the `package.json` file it was showing in dependencies as **"@angular/flex-layout": "^6.0.0-beta.18",**

Now in the new `branch` i am trying to install with the same command.Now in the `package.json` file, the dependencies is like this **"@angular/flex-layout": "^7.0.0-beta.19",** and getting the `errors` as shown in above image.

How can i install particular version of **flex-layout** means `version 6`??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To install a specific version you can add `@<verions>` to the package name, for example :

`npm install --save @angular/flex-layout@6.0.0-beta.16`

You can have the list of avaible versions on npmjs.org: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/flex-layout

Answer (score 3):

It seems that `@angular/flex-layout": "^7.0.0-beta.19"` is for angular v7.

Try using any **6.0.0-beta.18**

Release note says: (https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/releases)

feat: upgrade to TypeScript v3.1 (#860)

- Upgrade apps to Angular CLI v7
- Update versions in package.json to v7 for Angular and Material
- Update to TypeScript v3.1 and change the MatchMedia interface
  to match updated spec

And it seems that your `@angular/cli` and `typescript` is not same as of latest flex-layout

Comment: Thank for your guidance, but after installing specific version i,e versio-16 of flext-layout. In the `package.json` file it showing as beta version **( "@angular/flex-layout": "^6.0.0-beta.16",)**. Does it causes any issues later ?? Since it is in beta version.

Comment: Flex layout is always in beta and I have been using it since last 1 yrs

Answer (score 0):

`npm install --legacy-peer-deps` saved hours my life